# Problems in changing value of a runtime annotation with reflection (Java 17)

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, runtime, java-17

I'm stuck into trying to change the value of a `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` annotation with Java 17. I think my code has some problems also related to the Java 9 illegal reflective access.

That's what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
public static void changeAnnotationValue(String value) {
        Greeter oldAnnotation = Greetings.class.getAnnotation(Greeter.class);
        Greeter newAnnotation = new Greeter() {

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return oldAnnotation.annotationType();
            }

            @Override
            public String value() {
                return value;
            }
        };
        try {
            Method method = Greetings.class.getDeclaredMethod("annotationData", null);
            method.setAccessible(true);

            Field annotations = method.getClass().getDeclaredField("annotations");
            annotations.setAccessible(true);

            Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> map = (Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation>) annotations.get(method);
            map.put(Greeter.class, newAnnotation);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            //Handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Only found ways online for Java 8

Comment: I am not sure that this is supported. Annotation values must be compile-time constants.

Comment: @Turing85 yes, it is. You can change value of runtime annotations.

Comment: [JLS, §9.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1) and [JLS, §9.7.1 - §9.7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) suggest otherwise (not explicitly, but implicitly). Do you have an example of some code that changes the value of an annotation at runtime? Or a reference that says it is possible?

Comment: @Turing85 yes, here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params

Comment: Hm... For me, the program already fails on `Method method = Greetings.class.getDeclaredMethod("annotationData", null);`, reporting that method `"annotationData"` could not be found. This looks like something that is very dependent on the java versio used. I tested with 17. The baeldung article also only  talks about java 7 and java 8. And the sample code is missing from their github (or at least not where they linked to). Are you running with a jdk in version 8?

Comment: @Turing85 Only tried with Java 17. Can’t find another way to do the same thing…ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry....

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to do something that is not supported by the platform.  The various tricks you've seen depend on breaking into platform internals in unsupported ways.  You should not be surprised to see these stop working.  The supported way would be to modify the source and recompile.